Which keywords from the header go into the cpp file?
If I split the code into .h and .cpp files, which of the following keywords used in the header must also be used in the .cpp file and which must not go into the .cpp file:
const, virtual, override, noexcept, constexpr

and in which order do they have to be used, i.e. is the following order correct:
virtual constexpr int foo() const override noexcept;

Please feel free to give a rule if such exists.

constexpression is not a keyword - you presumably mean constexpr, while override is not a keyword.   In any event, (1) by convention, .cpp files #include header files, and header files can (optionally) #include each other and (2) the effect of #include is to perform text substitution and replace the content of the #include directive with content of the named file.  Hence any construct (including any keyword) that appears in a header can appear in a source file, and vice versa.

It makes no difference which file they are in; the "file" is pretty much a meaningless concept in C++. The difference is between member definitions inside and outside the class definition and is described in any decent book.

Did you mean to ask whether a keyword used in a declaration of a function or variable must be repeated in the definition of same, when the definition is supplied after the declaration?

@tbxfreeware yes, that#s exaclty what I meant.

There is also a difference between must be repeated and can be repeated. Some of us prefer to have a virtual on all virtual functions. even when not needed.

override is a specifier, which means it is not a keyword, rather it is an identifier that has a special meaning when used in a specific context.  (The other specifier in C++ is final.  There may be more in the future.)  Why not a keyword?  WG21 is very conservative for adding new keywords to the language, and usually repurposes an existing keyword instead (which is why some keywords like inline have very different semantics now than what they had originally, or static has dozens of different meanings in different contexts).

const and noexcept will have to be duplicated in the source since they are part of the signature of a function.

The "virtual" specifiers are part of the class definition and only belong on the class member specification, which in this case is the declaration (with or without definition) of a non-static class member function. A member being "virtual" is a property of the class, not of the function type.
The "qualifiers" (const, volatile, &, &&) and the constexpr/consteval specifiers are part of the function, and thus must appear on every declaration of the (member) function (including the defining one, regardless of whether that's inline or out of line):
// Class definition of X; specifies the members of X.
struct X : Base {
  virtual void f() const;  // virtual and override
  void g() && override;    // are part of "being a member"
};

// Function declarations and definitions:
// qualifiers are part of the function.
void X::f() const { /* ... */ }
void X::g() &&    { /* ... */ }

This has nothing to do with .h and .cpp files per se, though one would typically place an out-of-line definition into a .cpp file. (If it were left in a header, it would lead to repeated definitions when the header is included in different translation units, unless one of the declarations were also explicitly specified as inline. By contrast, inline definitions of class member functions are implicitly inline.)

Good answer, and thanks for pointing me to ref-qualifiers. TIL !

This list is quite incomplete. noexcept-specifications, language linkage, constraints, etc. also need to match between declaration and definition. Or I guess generally, anything that's part of the function signature.

@JanSchultke Yes, true - that's why I was trying to point at the underlying distinction beween "class member" and "function type". The details will surely change as C++ evolves. Thanks for the additions.

In short, you need to repeat parts of a function that are part of its type and/or necessary to make two functions correspond.
Therefore, you need to repeat:

function parameters and the return type
const and volatile qualifiers
ref-qualifiers (& and &&)
requires clauses
noexcept specifications

Generally, for a function declaration in a header to match the definition in the source file, the declarations need to correspond.
For functions, this means they need to be corresponding overloads (see [basic.scope.scope]):

Two function or function template declarations declare corresponding overloads if:

both declare functions with the same non-object-parameter-type-list, equivalent ([temp.over.link]) trailing requires-clauses (if any, except as specified in [temp.friend]), and, if both are non-static members, they have corresponding object parameters, or
both declare function templates with corresponding signatures and equivalent template-heads and trailing requires-clauses (if any).


Let's focus on just the first bullet, since you're not asking about templates.
Firstly, the parameter list needs to be the same (not counting the explicit object parameter, i.e. this auto and other forms).
Secondly, the object parameter needs to be the same, which means const, volatile, &, and && have to match.
Thirdly, the requires clause needs to be equivalent.
noexcept specifications also need to be the same because noexcept applies to the function type. You cannot have two corresponding declarations with different types:
int x(int);

int x(float);         // OK, x(float) does not correspond to x(int) and is a separate overload
int x(int) noexcept;  // error: x(int) declared with two different types

Everything else such as attributes, virtual, etc. apply to the declaration and don't have to be repeated in the definition.
